# I tried installing RubyGems, and now I get some errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First time asking a question, and i'm also a novice at ruby, so please be gentle. I'm running Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I recently tried to install RubyGems, as to aid my development in Ruby. Problem is, I get some strange errors when I installed it, and the same error when I try to run any script in my terminal. I am pretty stuck on what to do, so...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
    3: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'
    2: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:1231:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:1231:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:43:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Gem::BasicSpecification (NameError)
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? I have exactly the same problem after install ruby on ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

As per the description mentioned in the post it seems like there is a problem with the current version of bundler.

Try running the below mentioned command:

```
gem update bundler
```

If the problem still does not resolves then you might need to run the below mentioned command:

```
gem update --system
```

Above command will be updating all the gems in the system based on the ruby version.

Comment: Thanks, but both of these didn't work. I've tried re-installing ruby as well.